# Translatable Categories

Tags: translation

Hi I am working on new multilingual WordPess theme using loco translate plugin,

I can't find categories names in translation files.

Is there a way to make it translatable!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you mean the categories that you publish the posts in them?

Comment: Yes that what I mean exactly.